# Bootstrap fill table vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to fill the table vertically? What I mean is like this

instead of populating like this

---

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 

data1-1 data1-2 data1-3 data1-4 data1-5 data1-6 


data2-1 data2-2 data2-3 data2-4 data2-5 data2-6
```

---

```
Column1     Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6 
data1-1     data2-1
data1-2     data2-2
data1-3     data2-3
data1-4     data2-4
data1-5     data2-5
data1-6     data2-6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS trick for displaying columns instead of rows with `<tr>`

```
tr { 
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
}

th, td { 
  display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can play with the html table the way you have mentioned above. It's just a matter of how you want your data to be represented. In the above example you have 2 rows and 6 columns, whereas you have 2 columns and 6 rows in the other. Try this plunk: 
                                         http://plnkr.co/edit/u0aBeB3ABvR7m35hBLHk?p=preview

It has 2 tables showing how you can fit in both forms of data. Hope it helps you. Here is the HTML code:

First Table

```
<table>
  <thead>Table display
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Firstname</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>Hally</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>Mona</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lastname</td>
      <td>Evans</td>
      <td>Ema</td>
      <td>Wang</td>
      <td>Lizzie</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>Second Table</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>Evans</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hally</td>
    <td>Ema</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>Wang</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mona</td>
    <td>Lizzie</td> 
  </tr>
```